# View is sending null value to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, razor, model-view-controller

I have a view file from where I am trying to send the url to the controller file
My view file looks like:

```
@model WebRole1.Models.CodeSnippet

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<p>
     @Html.ActionLink("Preview", "Preview", new { Model.URL }) |       
</p>
```

In the above code I am trying to send the url value to the controller file. Function in the controller file looks like

```
public ActionResult Preview(object zipPath)
{
    // some operation...
}
```

However for some reason view is sending null value to the controller. i.e. when Preview method of controller gets called `zipPath` value remains null. What can be the issue?

Comment: Where do you set the URL?

Comment: Please post your *real* code.

Comment: to the controller file, after that I am performing some operation using the url

Comment: You are constructing an object here: `new { Model.URL }`.  By default, since you don't provide a property name, it will be `URL`.  The argument on your method is named `zipPath`, not `URL`, so that won't match up.  Try `new { zipPath=Model.URL }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your action method is *waiting* for property with the name `zipPath`. But, since you don't provide a name for a property in your anonymous object, it will be `URL` by default.

So, change your code to:

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Preview", "Preview", new { zipPath = Model.URL })
```

***Additional information:***

If you have included `zipPath` as a URL segment in your route, then the value will assigned to this segment by the routing segment.  Otherwise, the value we supplied will be added as part of the query string.